# QGIS/GeoJSON: Dissolve featurecollection consisting of polygons and multipolygons into a large multipolygon

Tags: qgis, geojson, dissolve

I've read [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118547/how-can-i-convert-geojson-with-multiple-polygons-and-multipolygons-into-single-m) question. I would like to know how to do this in QGIS.

I have a Geojson file with a `featurecollection`, starting with:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[5.21846588339...
```

But there are also quite a few MultiPolygons in the collection.

When I do the following:

- Import the GeoJSON file in QGIS (add layer --> vector layer)
- Select all of it
- Do a dissolve (vector --> geoprocessing tools --> dissolve)

Then all the **normal** polygons get merged into a giant multipolygon, but not the multipolygons in the original collection.

What is the best way to include them? I've thought about manually "splitting" them into polygons in the geojson file with a text editor (because individual feature metadata is not important/removed after the dissolve anyway). But I have to do this more often in the future, and it seems like this should be doable automatically :)

### Before Dissolve:

[image: Before Dissolve]

### After Dissolve:

[image: After Dissolve]

Answer (score 1):

You can do a "Multipart to singlepart" before dissolving.